# Share a folder on network without passwords"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have one folder on a Windows Server 2012 R2 that we want to share without passwords"
We need to provide the access of folder to another machine that is in same network but not in domain.
We need to share it without password verification.

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure all computers are connected to same LAN**

1. **start --> Run --> fsmgmt.msc**
2. shared folders dialogue will open in that right-click

   **shares --> new share --> browse through the folder you want to share**
   and then in permissions Add Guest and change the permissions to access all then click OK.
3. Enter IP(shared PC IP) in the LAN computer PC

It should be open.

Comment: Not sure about other versions but at least in Server 2016, when connecting to the share from a Win 10 PC it will still ask for the username/password when trying to connect to the folder. Even if you grant access to Guest and Everyone

Answer (score 3):

1. In the computer that has the share, browse to Settings >> Network & Internet >> Status >> Sharing Options (or browse to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings)
2. Advanced Sharing Options Window pops up
3. Choose the "All Networks" section so it opens the options
4. Scroll down to "Password Protected Sharing"
5. Choose the Option to "Turn Off Password Protected Sharing"
6. Click "Save Changes"

This method is only suggested if you aren't running a domain controller. I use this method on a Windows 2016 Server which has shares I need to access from PC's that are not part of any network domain. If you are running a domain controller, you want to handle everything through group policy as this method will allow anyone on your network to access the share.

If doing the above alone does not give you access then you will also need to edit the share permisions to and add the "Everyone" group object. The permission you give "Everyone" will determine whether users who access the share can read or write to the share.

1. Open Computer Management.
2. If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Yes.
3. In the console tree, click System Tools, click Shared Folders, and then click Shares.
4. In the details pane, right-click the shared folder, and then click Properties.
5. On the Share Permissions tab, set the permissions you want:
6. To assign permissions to a shared folder to a user or group, click Add.
7. In the Select Users, Computers, or Groups dialog box, type "Everyone", and then click OK.
8. Verify the permissions for the "Everyone Group" you just added.
9. Click Okay
10. Test

**References:**

[Set Permissions for Shared Folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726004(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_interface)

[How to Create Network File Shares with No Passwords in Windows 8](https://www.howtogeek.com/126214/how-to-create-network-file-shares-with-no-passwords-in-windows-8/)

Answer (score 1):

enable guest access and share it with guest this should do it. Else you need to make sure everyone is part of the domain and that that share is available to all the domain users. Sharing it with the users group should do the trick.

Comment: but if I enable guest access then also need set password for guest account and it will ask password of guest while access

Comment: If you activate the Guest user account on the server, the account can be used to access only the shared folders on the server that the administrator specifies. Additionally, if you activate the Guest user account on the server and on a computer that is connected to the network, users who log on to the network computer as Guest can automatically access the shared folders on the server without being prompted for a password.
The server automatically assigns a blank password for the Guest account.

Comment: once you enable guest then you would want to share it via the everyone group.

Comment: you can also allow anonymous access https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755781(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the 'Everyone' in the security folder and provide read and write access then share the folder (or) Right-click the folder and select Share with Specific People and then add 'Everyone' with Read/Write this will allow every user can access that folder.

Comment: This lets everyone access the share with the specified rights (read only, contribute, etc.) but not without a valid username and password (either a local account or domain account). The word "everyone" here is a bit misleading.